# Node/NPM: If I upgrade my node version, should I rebuild the package-lock file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, package-lock.json

I am using node version 11 and want to use 12.6.  I had the package-lock.json file committed.  When upgrading, should I remove my node module, `npm install`, and commit the new `package-lock.json` file?

Answer (score 1):

No, node updates are backward compatible.

Comment: thanks.  What about if other developers join team, won't that be an issue then since they'll have a differing package-lock.json when running `npm install` on node 12 than what was built and committed to the repo from node 11?

Comment: Still chuckling about this.. good one

Answer (score 1):

In package.json, there's a [property](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines) called `engine` to specify which versions of node.js that package can be used, when upgrading to new node version please check that.

Comment: I do have that in packages already:  ```  "engines": {
    "node": "12.6.0",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  },